# Как сделать чтобы web уведомление после подписки поялялось 1 раз?

Tags: javascript, push-уведомления

Чтобы уведомление после перезагрузки не повторялось, если сообщение человек видел и оно такое же, но если сообщение изменилось, то у человека оно высвечивалось?

```
<script>
 function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";

}
 function sendNotification(title, options) {
// Проверим, поддерживает ли браузер HTML5 Notifications
if (!("Notification" in window)) {
alert('Ваш браузер не поддерживает HTML Notifications, его необходимо обновить.');
}

// Проверим, есть ли права на отправку уведомлений
else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
// Если права есть, отправим уведомление
var notification = new Notification(title, options);

function clickFunc() {window.location.href = 'http://aviaciya.com/specpredlozheniya_aviakompanij/';}

notification.onclick = clickFunc;
}

// Если прав нет, пытаемся их получить
else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
// Если права успешно получены, отправляем уведомление
if (permission === "granted") {
var notification = new Notification(title, options);

} else {
alert('Вы запретили показывать уведомления'); // Юзер отклонил наш запрос на показ уведомлений
}
});
} else {
// Пользователь ранее отклонил наш запрос на показ уведомлений
// В этом месте мы можем, но не будем его беспокоить. Уважайте решения своих пользователей.
}}</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async>
sendNotification('Зимние скидки на авиабилеты!', {
body: 'Распродажа, сезонные скидки',
icon: 'http://avia-avia.ru/image/samolet_p.png',
dir: 'auto'
});</script>
```

Comment: а где вызывается: `createCookie` и проверяется значение кук?

Comment: @Grundy , Не знаю((, помогите допилить плиз

Comment: а откуда ты взял этот код?

Comment: С интернета, кто-то спрашивал такой вопрос но ответов не получил на иностранном сайте